# Converting a nodejs buffer into a javascript object with functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that converting a buffer to a json object is trivial with:

```
JSON.parse(buffer)
```

But what about converting a buffer that contains a javascript object with functions to a real javascript object ??

I have files that contact objects with functions and I need to read these files in and save them to another master object.

While the task of reading the files is not a problem, I cannot find any way of converting the buffer back into a real javascript object again.

This is a very simple example of a file 'test.js' that I am trying to load

```
{
    get:function(){return 'hello'},
    somevar: "xxx",
    put: function(){return 'world'} 
}
```

Reading this data in it is a buffer, I can't convert using JSON as this contains functions and I cannot read using utf8 encoding as it will become a string !

```
var funcs = {}
fs.readFile('test.js',function(err,buff){
  funcs['test'] = buff;
})
```

Is it possible to read a file and convert it into a real javascript object ?

## Edit

OK, I have found a solution but it is using the dreaded eval(), however this is backend code and as far as I can tell there's no way for anything to be injected by a user from the frontend, I would prefer not to use it but unless there's anything that will work without modifying the format of the files, I will use it:

```
var funcs = {}
fs.readFile('test.js','utf8',function(err,buff){
  eval('var_='+buff); 
  funcs['test'] = _;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you could use [the `Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). It's slightly safer than `eval` because it doesn't access the local scope. But it can still access global variables.

```
var script = buffer.toString('utf8');    // assuming the file is in UTF-8
var returnObject = new Function('return ' + script);
var myObject = returnObject();
```

Comment: Thanks David, I tried your suggestion and although it did not error, the object was not successfully created and I was unable to call the functions or read the vars.

Comment: What was the value of `script`? What was the value of `myObject`? The only way I can think this could have happened is if `script` has a newline character before the `{`. Then `'return ' + script` would consist of a `return` statement (meaning `return undefined;`) followed by a separate expression which is never reached when the function runs. If it does have newlines near the start, you could try `'return ' + script.replace(/^\s*/g, '')` to remove leading whitespace.

Comment: David you were right, the newlines and spaces caused the conversion to fail, I used script.trim() to clean it up and it works !

Comment: Oops, I spoke too soon, I was right the first time. If you use my simple test.js in the original post and try and call get it should fail. I have reverted to eval() and it's working again.

Comment: What's gone wrong this time? Does `get` need access to variables in the scope? If that's the problem then you should be able to fix it by making those variables arguments to the function. For example: if `get: function() { return x+y; }`, then do `var returnObject = new Function('x','y','return ' + script.trim()); var myObject = returnObject(x, y);`.

Comment: Also, another way round the problem of leading whitespace would be to enclose the whole thing in brackets: `'return (' + script + ')'`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the code you're dealing with, this approach may or may not suit your needs:

You can create a temporary file, say "test-module.js", which includes the object from "test.js" but with a module export prependend, for example:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function() { return 'hello' },
    somevar: 'xxx',
    put: function() { return 'world' } 
}
```

Then, from your main file, you can retrieve the file content already available as a Javascript object:

```
var funcs = {}
var buff = require('./test-module');
funcs['test'] = [buff.get, buff.put];
```

Would this solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but not really, I have thousands of files some have one or 2 lines some have hundreds of lines of code. This is an attempt to break up some very huge libraries into individual functions which can be maintained separately.